# How can I use a USB stick as the build directory for compiling OpenCV with cmake?

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install OpenCV to my Raspberry Pi by following this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

However, when I get to the build section with cmake, I do not have enough space to compile the package after building it. I read that you can use a USB stick to store the build data in, which seems to be the bulk of the data.

I have attempted to manually create a build folder on the usb stick, and copied the CMakeLists file over, but to no avail.

Apologies for lack of clarity on this question, I'm exceptionally new to Linux and don't even know how to provide additional details. A step-by-step guide for performing step 5 of the above guide, using a USB stick to store the bulk of the data, would be very much appreciated.

Edit: The section I am trying to use is:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I am trying to use media/usb/build as my build folder, but still want the package to install to the SD card. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to run `cmake ...` command in `/media/usb/build` folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this is a step I tried already (sorry again for lack of detail) that didn't work. I posted my solution above.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Comment: cmake works, but make does nothing